# three blured circles in background UI design challenge

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to create this kind of app background.it uses three circle in three parts of screen.
how to create a background color like this???
[image]

Comment: Can you please Specify the widget in the picture? Do you mean gradient container in the category section?

Comment: No i mean the scaffold background color.. the scaffold background color is not white. it is a mix of three blured circle with different colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

> BackdropFilter

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3F6FE),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
              top: -150,
              left: -150,
              child: Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                    color: Color(0xFFD8E4FC)),
              )),
          Positioned(
              top: 200,
              right: -150,
              child: Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                    color: Color(0xFFE8DCFC)),
              )),
          Positioned(
              bottom: -150,
              left: -150,
              child: Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                    color: Color(0xFFD8E4FC)),
              )),
          Container(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 50.0, sigmaY: 50.0),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result : [image: Blur background]

Answer (score 1):

Please check it, I think this is what you need.
As you can see, you can set `Colors.transparent` as the `color` of the container and then use `box-shadow` to create something like that picture.

```dart
class CustomScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomScaffold({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  coloredContainer(double size, Color color) => Container(
        width: size,
        height: size,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: color, blurRadius: 100),
          ],
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 152, 204, 246),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: -100,
            left: -100,
            child:
                coloredContainer(500, const Color.fromARGB(255, 104, 136, 224)),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 700,
            left: 100,
            child:
                coloredContainer(400, const Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 128, 226)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

result :

[image]